# How to Cut a shape inside objects

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to design a pie chart, so I create circles (each one in a separate layer) then I change them to something like that:

[image]

Now I want it to look like that:

[image]

Of course I can create a small blank circle and put it in the middle, but I want it to be transparent (logically impossible) . I tried to use the path division operation between the two switched circles and it works, but I don't want to combine them (also they will have the same style).

I'm open to any other suggestions or alternatives.

Comment: I would think a clip or a mask could do it easily. Welcome to GraphicDesign!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Once you have finished creating the segments in different layers. Create a circle at the center.
2. Duplicate the circle. Now select path- division twice, selecting a circle & a segment each at a time. The resulting path looks like this image(segments are not combined retaining the assigned style intact).[image: image 1].

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify What software do you use, if Illustrator add circle like this

[image]

select both objects 
then go to Window-->Pathfinder Click to "Minus Front"

[image]

It will come like this

[image]

You can apply the same method for the above(blue shape) object.

Comment: It's tagged Inkscape so I guess it's Inkscape

Answer (score 1):

Put the pie slices on the same layer

Duplicate the objects then

Path -> Union

Use
Path -> Exclusion

on the newly formed object with a circle to your liking

Path -> Break Apart

and discard the circle remnants

Select the pie slices and the new object making sure it's uppermost then

Object -> Clip -> Set

Though to be honest I would probably just either go with a circle matching the background colour. Doing the above ties you in to not changing the size of the slices ever or having to redo the above steps. It's a lot of extra faf and stuff you have to remember to keep an eye on for no real gain - it won't make the file smaller and resizing becomes way trickier than it needs to be.